# No org-babel execute function for R

Tags: r, emacs, org-mode

I am new to Org Mode, and trying to run R block code as shown below.

```
#+NAME: test
#+begin_src R: results output
library(tidyverse)
p <- mpg %>% ggplot() + aes(cty,hwy)
p + geom_point()
#+end_src
```

I am on MS Windows, and have the latest version of Emacs (27.2) with ESS, Org Mode installed.
Following the instructions, I added the following line to `init.el` file.

`(setq org-babel-R-command "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.0/bin/x64/R --slave --no-save")`

Is there something that I am missing here?

Comment: You need to `(load-library 'ob-R)` . If you want it in every emacs session in the future,  customize `org-babel-load-languages` to include an `(R . t)` element. See its doc string with `C-h v org-babel-load-languages`.

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Comment: unfortunately, I made changes to `init.el` file, and the variable `org-babel-load-languages`. There is a new error on location which I just haven't gotten around to fix.
`'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command'`

Comment: Update: Got this working with a few changes in addition to the suggestions you'd made.

Comment: @Neeraj Maybe open an answer with the changes you made that fixed the problem that way when people find this question they can also find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use
`(setq org-babel-R-command "C:/Progra~1/R/R-4.1.2/bin/x64/R --slave --no-save")`